# Что получается в случае использования $? в качестве параметра утилиты mesg?

Tags: linux, ос

Что получается в случае использования $? в качестве параметра утилиты mesg ?

Comment: Зависит от кода возврата последней (перед вызовом mesg) команды в данном шелле (терминале). Если она закончилась без ошибок, то $? == 0 и [mesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mesg.1.html) интерпретирует этот код, как `n`. $? == 1 интерпретируется как `y`, а на остальные значения mesg ругнется

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что для того, чтобы проверить, могут ли пользователи отправлять на мой терминал сообщения и вывести этот результат на экран, я вообще могу не использовать $?  ?
Изначально у меня было написано так, но преподаватель стал ругаться:
 mesg $? && echo "Сообщения разрешены" || echo "Сообщения запрещены"

Comment: Правильно. Если на самом деле вы хотите заменить стандартные сообщения mesg, вызванного без аргумента, то я бы написал вот так:  `(mesg >/dev/null && echo "Сообщения разрешены") || echo "Сообщения запрещены"`

Comment: Спасибо большое!!